# Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null

Tags: angular

I just upgraded to `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.25.5`and `@angular/common@2.4.2`and one of my modules routing started failing.

I have `TemplateModule` which has

```typescript
export const TEMPLATE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'template',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'editor',
        component: TemplateEditorComponent
      }, {
        path: 'selector',
        component: TemplateSelectorComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

These can be used in 2 different modules.
On first one no transformation is required

```typescript
export const PREVIEW_ROUTES: Routes = [
  ***
  ...TEMPLATE_ROUTES
];
```

but on second one

```typescript
export const CONTENT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  ***
  ...TEMPLATE_ROUTES.map(parseTemplateRoutes)
];

export function parseTemplateRoutes(route) {
  route.canActivate = [CannotEnterMultistep];
  return route;
}
```

Previous to this update this was working and valid but now i'm getting

`ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null`

Any idea on how to do it without replicating the Template routes array?

Comment: this is something related to lazy loading...if you're not using lazy-loading, I would try to remove the `children` array, leaving just 3 `paths` object

Comment: but then I would loose hierarchy, wouldn't I?

Comment: yes, indeed. I'm suggesting this to see if the error goes way...if so, then you know that there is something doing lazy-loading when you using use `children` sintaxe in the new version...at least you'll understand the error and make it a little bit easy to find out why.